# Setting column width for previously created HTML tables when apply flexigrid

Tags: jquery, html-table, flexigrid

I am using jQuery flexigrid to design my previously created HTML tables. But how can I set column width for this table.

```
<table id="myTable">
   <tr>
     <th>Column1</th>
     <th>Column2</th>
     <th>Column3</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>RC1</td>
     <td>RC2</td>
     <td>RC3</td>
   <tr>
<table>
```

And jQuery Code I am using is :

```
$("#myTable").flexigrid();
```

I want to fix the column width so how can I do that?

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: You can fix the headers in flexigrid() method and with this their width as well. I tried it but table rows were expanding more than the header width. So I left it and tried other plugin's.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep working on it.

Comment: Sure @Emma ..  If you are using json or xml data, then its better to go with this for creating table.